# Direct sum and linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be two finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $k$ and let $L : V \to W$ be a linear map.  Given a subspace $W_1$ of $W$, is it possible to say when
$$W =  L(V) \oplus W_1? $$

That is, are there conditions for $L$ so that $L(V)$ is the complement of $W_1$ (or conditions for $W_1$)?

For example: for $V=W$ and $W_1=\ker(L)$, we have $V=L(V) \oplus \ker(L)$ whenever $L$ is idempotent ($L^2=L$). In the general case, is there a similar result?

Thanks

Comment: It is always possible. Take a basis for the inage of $L$, extend to a basis for the whole $W$, and the span of the newly added vectors is the desired $W_1$. This complement is of course non-unique in general.

Comment: Were you really only asking whether a subspace of a finite dimensional space always has a complement?

Comment: My question is not well formulated, indeed. I will edit it.